# view any current FTP on TFS or Web Server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, tfs, ftp, webserver

I am a little new to software engineering in general. I am going to need to set up FTP on our TFS server or our Web Server. Before I can do that I need to look at whether we have existing FTPs on either to ensure that the company didn't set one up for this particular situation before and just never put anything into it. There is also an existing FTP for a different reason on one of the servers (I think the TFS) so I know I should be able to see one somewhere.

I see nothing in the Source control explorer for the TFS or in IIS manager for the Web Server to show me existing FTPs set up. I am using windows 7 professional and VS2010 and 2012. Where can I look to find these?

Thanks

Comment: I actually got some advice from a senior guy here to remote desktop into the TFS Server, look turn on its IIS Manager in the control panel and look there. That sounds like it will solve the issue we'll see how it goes

Comment: **Why** do you want FTP on your TFS server? This is a classic XY Problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have found, TFS doesn't use FTP, there's no FTP relationship to TFS, etc. TFS provides a web site and Web API access to TFS clients, all using HTTP, with custom ports, usually 8080.

If there's an FTP site on your TFS Server, then someone/something else put it there, TFS didn't....

Comment: yeah, we were worried about security verification and keeping a separate server space for the client but we found a workaround with http in a secured fashion. Thank you